# Sums of special vectors

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, banach-spaces

Let $v$ be a vector obtained by taking a sum of $k$ vectors the of the form $(0,0,\ldots,0, -n, *,*,\ldots,*)$, where $"*"$ stands for either $0$ or $1$, and the position of the $-n$ entry can vary for each summand of $v$. We also require the sum of all entries of $v$ to equal to zero.

Is it possible that $$\frac{\|v\|_1}{k\cdot n}$$ is arbitrary small?

Comment: I think it can be equal to $1$ in some cases. For instance when you take two vectors which are orthogonal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $n=1$, fix $k$, and consider the $k$ vectors
\begin{eqnarray}
v_1 &=& (-1,1,0,0,0,0,\ldots) \\
v_2 &=& (0,-1,1,0,0,0,\ldots) \\
v_3 &=& (0,0,-1,1,0,0,\ldots) \\
v_4 &=& (0,0,0,-1,1,0,\ldots) \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots
\end{eqnarray}
Here, each $v_i\in \mathbb{R}^d$ where $d>k$.
Let $v=v_1+\cdots+v_k$. Then $v=(-1,0,0,\ldots,0,1,0,\dots)$, $||v||_1 = 2$, and $\frac{||v||_1}{nk}\to 0$ as $k\to\infty$. This is easily generalized to $n>1$ if you want.

Comment: Thanks, Will, I should correct myself, I would like it to have for an increasing sequence of $n$

Comment: @user26565 Then generalize to $n>1$ and allow $n$ and $k$ to get big together. For this trick to work, I think one must allow $k$ to grow large compared to $n$, but $n$ can grow large simultaneously.

Comment: OK, I agree, one can do this just by shifting.